# Получить выделенный текст, android

Tags: java, android, text, browsers

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно каким-то образом перехватывать выделенный в chrome (желательно, в других андроид-браузерах тоже) текст и передавать его для обработки в моё приложение. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: я надеюсь, что невозможно. Если бы было возможно - это бы стало большущей дырой в безопасности.